# Optimal search for opposing unit vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, computational-complexity

Given a finite set of 3D unit vectors, what is the optimal way to discover whether any pairs from that set point in opposite directions, i.e. have a negative dot product. In $O(n^2)$ time, we can compare every such pair, but I am sure we can do better than that.

Comment: Do you mean opposite pairs $\hat{v}_i = -\hat{v}_j$, $i \ne j$? I don't see how the unit vectors would *pair* otherwise, since $\hat{v}_i \cdot \hat{v}_j \le 0$ just means they are in different halfspaces; you pick any vector $\hat{v}_i$, which divides all the other vectors $\hat{v}_j$, $j \ne i$, into two subsets: those that are in the same halfspace as $\hat{v}_i$, and those that are in the other halfspace... it is not a one-to-one relation, so no "pairs" formed.

Comment: Any pair $<\hat v_i, \hat v_j>$ satisfies the condition if $\hat v_i \cdot \hat v_j \le 0$, which does mean they are in different half spaces. The question is whether the set of such pairs is empty. Indeed you might find such a pair by starting from any vector $\hat v_i$, and test all the other unit vectors to see if they are in the same half space, at $O(n)$ cost. If you find one that is not, you are done! But if you don't find one, then you have to test $\hat v_{i+1}$, $\hat v_{i+2}$ etc, for a total cost of $O(n^2)$. The puzzle is to find a faster algorithm.

Comment: I hesitate to comment too much, since I wouldn't want to send anyone down the wrong path. But just to make sure I stated the problem clearly, let me help with your mental picture. Rather than a ball of vectors pointing all different directions, which would have many many pairs $<\hat v_i, \hat v_j>$ s.t. $\hat v_i \cdot \hat v_j \le 0$, picture a bunch of vectors pointing in nearly the same direction. Now, the question is, does the one on the left (wlog) tilt far enough away from the one on the right to have a negative dot product.

Comment: By your definition, your set of pairs may contain up to $N(N-1)/2$ unique pairs. Simply constructing the set therefore requires $N(N-1)/2$ operations (to find out whether each possible unique pair is in the set), and therefore has $O(N^2)$ time and space complexity. (Just because you know the set to be smaller than that does not help, because you still have to check each unique pair.)

Comment: If you drop the pair concept, and look at a set of vectors with a nonzero average (i.e., "bunched"), you can find the average vector in $O(N)$ time, and then classify all the vectors based on that in $O(N)$ time as well, yielding $O(N)$ in total. You can even pick some angle $\theta$, and choose the vectors that have a larger angle (smaller cosine of angle) to the average vector, to reduce the set of outlying vectors; then find out *their* pairwise dot products to determine which vectors in fact are considered outliers, reducing the effect of the bunch average vector.

Comment: I think you're on to something! Thinking of them bunched up, if the magnitude of the average vector is less than $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, we know there must be at least one pair with negative dot product. Which is nice, because that handles the degenerate case when the average is zero.

Comment: The next step, though, is to classify each vector relative to the average. If we have any with negative dot product, we can stop. But, vectors between 45 and 90 degrees from the average could still be candidates. I think we have to search those vectors against every other vector next. At least that's $O(N \cdot M)$ ($M$ is the number of vectors between 45 and 90 degrees from the average), which is an improvement on $O(N^2)$ at least! I think for my case $M$ will often be small so it might be good enough.

Comment: You could start by counting the number of unit vectors in each orthant (this obviously being $O(N)$). Vectors in opposite orthants ($+++$ to $---$, $+-+$ to $-+-$, $--+$ to $++-$, and so on) always have a negative dot product. Also, note that if you use $O(N)$ to find the $M$ vectors that are at least 45 degrees away from the bunch, you need only $M(M-1)/2$ (or $O(M^2)$; not $O(NM)$) to find out if the outliers have pairs of vectors in different halfspaces. ("Frayed bunch"?)

Comment: I think I need to compare the frayed vectors with all the other vectors, and not just each other. Consider the relatively simple case of N identical vectors, and just one frayed vector that is 89.9 degrees from there. The average will be very close to the identical vectors when N is large. But I need to compare the frayed vector with all of them. If any one were actually 0.2 degrees further away from the frayed vector, we'd get a negative dot product. And that 0.2 degrees would not be enough to put it into the frayed set.